# What is the package for pycairo in Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, python

Plots, a plotting program, [requires](https://github.com/alexhuntley/Plots/pull/16) the dependency [pycairo](https://pypi.org/project/pycairo/).

The Ubuntu repositories have two packages with the similar name, `python3-gi-cairo` and `python3-cairo`.

Which among these `apt` packages correspond to the PyPI package `pycairo`? I went through the package descriptions of `python3-gi-cairo` and `python3-cairo`, but am not sure which one is the one corresponding to `pycairo`, or if both are needed.

In general, how to find the relevant `apt` package in such cases, where two python packages have similar names?

---

Note: I am the maintainer of the PPA for Plots. I need to use the relevant apt package as a dependency in `debian/control`. Installing with pip is not an option.

Comment: Hints : https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python3-gi-cairo → Python 3 Cairo bindings for the GObject library. .......... And `python3-cairo` https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python3-cairo

Comment: For building you probably need python3-cairo-dev . See https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/pycairo .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the description for the `python3-gi-cairo` package (`apt show python3-gi-cairo`)...

```plaintext
GObject is an abstraction layer that allows programming with an object
 paradigm that is compatible with many languages. It is a part of Glib,
 the core library used to build GTK+ and GNOME.
 .
 This package contains the Python 3 Cairo bindings for GObject. It is mostly
 used by other bindings to map their GObjects to Python objects.
```

And here is the description for the `python3-cairo` package (`apt show python3-cairo`)...

```plaintext
This package contains modules that allow you to use the Cairo vector
 graphics library in Python3 programs.
```

So, the second one (`python3-cairo`) would be the package you want.

That said, [the maintainers of the `pycairo` suggest that you install it via `pip`](https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html). For Ubuntu/Debian, they say to install the headers and `pkg-config`

```sh
$ sudo apt install libcairo2-dev pkg-config python3-dev
```

and then to install the `pip3` package

```sh
$ pip3 install pycairo
```